# Logout functionality Error

Tags: javascript

I have an ASP.NET Web application where in I have a Logout functionality. Below is my code for Logout in JavaScript.
But I don't want the Logout to close the Browser. I want to implement a functionality where the user clicks Logout and
it should clear the cookies/session and force the application to the login.[Like this Login pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeVtj.png)Also it should run the Logout functionality across all 
the browsers(Chrome, IE,FF). My current code doesn't work for Chrome.
Would someone help me with this issue?

```
function Logout() {
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to close the browser?')) {
    open(location, '_self').close();
} else {
    // Do nothing!
}
```

}

Comment: Usually the server will clear the session, and that will be enough because when the user tries to hit a secure page they'll redirected to the login. You may not be able to remove the cookie if it is http-only

Comment: I don't think js will clear the sessions.. the server side should take care of that

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JavaScript will be able clear the session. the server side should take care of that.

try

```
protected void LogoutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Roles.DeleteCookie();
        Session.Clear();
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: I am using Windows Authentication in my application. Will the above code work for that?

Comment: try the code it should work!.. I'm not that into ASP did it a long time ago

Comment: For my application, the cookies are not getting cleared. So even after hitting logout my old credentials are saved, I am not able to login as different user. any more suggestions plz?